# Can I generate a SHA1 in Perl or PHP?

Tags: php, perl, hex, sha1

Verotel requires some data to be hashed with sha1_hex function. What exactly is it? No info about it in the whole internet. They say "SHA-1 hash is used (hexadecimal output)". Sha1 with hex output?

Heres one example which I can't seem to reproduce:

> sha1_hex("abc777X:description=some description of product:priceAmount=51.20:priceCurrency=EUR:shopID=60678:version=1")
>
> =  04d87d2718767ea0bef259c436ec63e3cde05be2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
echo sha1('abc777X:description=some description of product:priceAmount=51.20:priceCurrency=EUR:shopID=60678:version=1');
```

Actually, that `sha1_hex` is named `sha1()` in php. Here is an example, working on your input: http://codepad.org/9fLlr9VJ

Answer (score 7):

```
$ perl -e 'use Digest::SHA qw(sha1_hex); print sha1_hex("abc777X:description=some description of product:priceAmount=51.20:priceCurrency=EUR:shopID=60678:version=1")'
04d87d2718767ea0bef259c436ec63e3cde05be2
```

The [SHA-1 hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sha-1) produces a 20 byte output.  If you represent those 20 bytes in hexadecimal, you get 40 characters.

Answer (score 7):

For Perl: [Digest::SHA](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Digest%3a%3aSHA) (updated from Digest::SHA1).

```
perl -MDigest::SHA=sha1_hex -le'print sha1_hex("abc777X:description=some description of product:priceAmount=51.20:priceCurrency=EUR:shopID=60678:version=1")'
04d87d2718767ea0bef259c436ec63e3cde05be2
```

Comment: Digest::SHA1 is deprecated.  [Digest::SHA](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Digest::SHA) became core in Perl 5.10; please use that instead.

Comment: @cjm, I'll update to reflect the preferable core version, but I'd like to know where the deprecation notice is.

Comment: I don't think it's officially deprecated, but now that Digest::SHA is a core module, and does everything that Digest::SHA1 does (and more), it's best to stick with Digest::SHA.

Comment: The SHA1 algorithm itself *is* deprecated, and using Digest::SHA in the first place perhaps provides a tiny bit easier upgrade to more complex SHA algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ php -r 'var_dump(sha1("abc777X:description=some description of product:priceAmount=51.20:priceCurrency=EUR:shopID=60678:version=1"));'
string(40) "04d87d2718767ea0bef259c436ec63e3cde05be2"
$
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, the function is [`sha1`](http://php.net/sha1), not `sha1_hex`.